# SQL query , retrieve except last 10 products with lowest product number

Tags: sql

I got stuck on this, I would like to retrieve the number of all products, except for the last 10 products with the lowest product number.

I have tried this but I know how to check if its right code or wrong could someone confirm?

```
SELECT P1.PRODNR
FROM PRODUCT P1
WHERE 10 < (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM PRODUCT P2
            WHERE P1.PRODNR < P2.PRODNR)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Subquery` to get the list of low numbers to exclude

```
SELECT P1.PRODNR
FROM PRODUCT P1
WHERE PRODNR not in
(SELECT top 10 PRODNR 
FROM PRODUCT P2 
order by PRODNR)  -- assuming product number is a number
```

Comment: This is likely to raise an error the subquery returned more than 1 row, you need `max(prodnr)`.

Comment: true..  `not in` should suffice

Comment: it gives me an error. syntax at line 4.  for example: this works great finding the three highest product numbers. SELECT P1.PRODNR
FROM PRODUCT P1
WHERE 3 >
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM PRODUCT P2
WHERE P1.PRODNR < P2.PRODNR)

Comment: change your OP if you want to a different solution

Comment: so my query above (in the main question) should be correct then?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of a CTE and `row_number`

```
with n as (
    select prodnr, Row_Number() over(order by prodnr) rn
    from products
)
select prodnr
from n
where rn>10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of acheiving your task:

```
SELECT P1.PRODNR
FROM PRODUCT P1
WHERE P1.PRODNR < 
      (select min(prodnr) from 
        (SELECT top 10 PRODNR FROM PRODUCT P2 
         ORDER BY PRODNR DESC) P3
       )
```

Comment: top 10 returning unordered list

Comment: @RoMEoMusTDiE it does not matter if they are ordered or not. the MIN() will pick the lowest of them

Comment: if the list is `1-22`  but your `top 10` returned `random numbers` ie. `1,2,3,11,20,21,22,10,6,4` so what's your minimum number?

Comment: @RoMEoMusTDiE I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the operator sign in subquery

```
SELECT P1.PRODNR
FROM PRODUCT P1
WHERE 25 <= (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM PRODUCT P2
            WHERE P1.PRODNR > P2.PRODNR)
```